# SAS automail not working

Tags: email, sas

I am new at SAS and I have this SAS macro, it will send me a email when the process has finished, but it is not working properly.

In the log just say macros's name like it work but the email is not coming to my inbox.

```
%macro mailing()
 data _null_;

  start = %eval(%sysfunc(today(), mmddyy5)-1);
  endd =  %eval(%sysfunc(today(), mmddyy5)-8);
run;

FILENAME mail EMAIL
  SUBJECT=" corporative subject"
  FROM='corporativemail@server.com'
  SENDER='corporativemail@server.com'
  TO=("mymail@server.com")


  DATA _NULL_;
  FILE mail;
    PUT "Hi,";
    PUT "here goes &start. - $endd. ";
    PUT "Best Regards,";
    PUT "me";

RUN;
%mend

%macro mailing()
```

By the way, I do not know if those date variables are properly defined

Comment: Contact the email server administrator. The code looks fine to me at a glance but this is going to be impossible for anyone outside your organisation to reproduce.

Comment: One possible typo - I suspect you meant `&endd` rather than `$endd.` - but that shouldn't have triggered any errors.

Comment: ok. then it is not the code failing, could be the mail server that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not actually calling the macro.  You only use `%macro` when *defining* a macro.

To call it, simply precede the macro name with a `%` symbol, as follows:

```
%mailing()
```